# Can not convert Resnet model trained with Keras to CoreML model

Tags: keras, coreml, coremltools

I need to convert a resnet50 model to CoreML model.
The Keras model trained is working correctly. I tried to convert it to Coreml but here is the error I get using coremltools :

```
ValueError: Keras layer '<class 'keras.layers.core.Lambda'>' not supported.
```

It seems that I have lambda functions in my model and Coreml does not support it... but what I do not understand where those lambda functions are coming from as I just used a standard resnet50 network for transfer learning. I only changed the last 1000-dense layer to a 4-dense layer, here is my code:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input

full_imagenet_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

output = full_imagenet_model.layers[-2].output
base_model = Model(full_imagenet_model.input, output)

top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2048, activation='softmax'))
top_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model = Model(base_model.input, top_model(base_model.output))
```

Here is the beginning and end of model summary:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       (None, 230, 230, 3)  0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)                  (None, 112, 112, 64) 9472        conv1_pad[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn_conv1 (BatchNormalization)   (None, 112, 112, 64) 256         conv1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 112, 112, 64) 0           bn_conv1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       (None, 114, 114, 64) 0           activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 56, 56, 64)   0           pool1_pad[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 56, 56, 64)   4160        max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
________________________________________________________________________________________________

(...)           
__________________________________________________________________________________
add_16 (Add)                    (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           bn5c_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 activation_46[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_49 (Activation)      (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           add_16[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
avg_pool (GlobalAveragePooling2 (None, 2048)         0           activation_49[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_1 (Sequential)       (None, 4)            8196        avg_pool[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 23,595,908
Trainable params: 23,542,788
Non-trainable params: 53,120
```

What is weird is when I load the model I trained and call the summary, here is what I get:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)               (None, 224, 224, 3)  0           input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_4 (Lambda)               (None, 224, 224, 3)  0           input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_5 (Model)                 (None, 4)            23595908    lambda_3[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_2 (Concatenate)      (None, 4)            0           model_5[1][0]                    
                                                                 model_5[2][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 23,595,908
Trainable params: 23,542,788
Non-trainable params: 53,120
```

I have no idea where the lambda layers come from.. any idea?

For information, here is how the training is done:

```
opt = Adam(lr=1e-3)

parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)

parallel_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = parallel_model.fit_generator(train_flow, train_flow.n // train_flow.batch_size,
                              epochs=200,
                              validation_data=val_flow,
                              validation_steps=val_flow.n,
                              callbacks=[clr, tensorboard, cb_checkpointer, cb_early_stopper])
```

Thanks for the help

**Edit1**

And here is how I save the model:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from pyimagesearch.clr_callback import CyclicLR

cb_early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_acc', patience = 30)
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = 'SAVED_MODELS/EPOCH:50_DataAug:Yes_Monitor:val-acc_DB2.hdf5', monitor = 'val_acc', save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format('model_EPOCH:50_DataAug:Yes_Monitor:val-acc_DB2'))
clr = CyclicLR(
        mode=CLR_METHOD,
        base_lr=MIN_LR,
        max_lr=MAX_LR,
        step_size= STEP_SIZE * (train_flow.n // train_flow.batch_size))
```

Comment: How did you save the model? Please add that code

Comment: Hi Matias, just edited my post with the code requested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the issue. The code I posted missed a part about multi_gpu_model used for training.

The probleme is that using multi_gpu is creating lambdas functions in the summary to load data in parralel.

I am looking now to implement the lambda functions in coremltools.